# Unable to save input picture data in state variable React.js

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to learn how the image upload process works with react. i have an input that takes image data in and a handler that sets that information to a variable but i am doing something incorrect and not sure what it is. 
I want to update picture in state with the picture information and leave the other items in state alone. When i do the below, and console.log after the state of picture stays null.

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userName: "",
      userEmail: "",
      picture: null
    };
    this.handleNewImage = this.handleNewImage.bind(this);
  }

  handleNewImage = event => {
    this.setState({
      picture: event.target.files[0]
    })
    console.log(this.state.picture); //gives null still 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type='file' onChange={this.handleNewImage} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are storing the file in state correctly, but since `setState` is asynchronous it will not end up in state right away. You can use the `setState` callback to make sure the state has changed. `this.setState({ picture: event.target.files[0] }, () => console.log(this.state.picture));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with images but rather an understanding of `setState`. React's `setState` is an async operation so you'd need to console log once the state update is complete:

```
handleNewImage = event => {
  this.setState({
    picture: event.target.files[0]
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.picture);
  });
}
```

More info here:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
- https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/

Comment: I did this but it's still showed 'undefined' whats happening